# How to detached realm objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

We are using realm and and want to detach the realm `Object`s, that is: create a static copy of the object that is a swift class / struct and can be passed around and modified independently of realm. We need this for two main reasons:

1. Abstracting the Persistence layer fully away, so no file should need to use realm `Object` or even import RealmSwift package.
2. Ability to pass around these objects, sometimes even across threads. (Realm objects are not thread safe)

**How can this be achieved?**

I see two "solutions", each with their reason for why it is not ideal (see below for code):

- **Method 1** [mapping realm objects to value types](https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/using-realm-with-value-types-b69947741e8b) and writing all CRUD operations by hand, that map between them as well. [This article does a similar thing.](https://ali-akhtar.medium.com/lightweight-persistence-layer-with-realm-realmswift-part-5-7f5a707e35e8) However, both of these posts are very old (4+ & 6+ years) and outdated (according to realm documentation: *"`@Persisted` declaration style replaces the `@objc dynamic` declaration notations from older versions of the SDK."*)
- **Method 2** creating a "DetachableObject" protocol and creating an extension for `Object` that conforms to it, [like here](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/3381#issuecomment-256243390). But this post is 7 years old and it doesn't really solve the *reason 1* stated above.

---

**Method 1**

```swift
public struct Publisher {
    public let identifier: Int
    public let name: String
}
final class PublisherObject: Object {
    dynamic var identifier = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
extension Publisher: Persistable {

    public init(managedObject: PublisherObject) {
        identifier = managedObject.identifier
        name = managedObject.name
    }

    public func managedObject() -> PublisherObject {
        let publisher = PublisherObject()

        publisher.identifier = identifier
        publisher.name = name

        return publisher
    }
}

// more see: https://gist.github.com/gonzalezreal/9d297c68435b9ee12bb1b009afd41d9a
```

**Method 2**

```swift
protocol DetachableObject: AnyObject {

    func detached() -> Self

}

extension Object: DetachableObject {

    func detached() -> Self {
        let detached = type(of: self).init()
        for property in objectSchema.properties {
            guard let value = value(forKey: property.name) else { continue }
            if let detachable = value as? DetachableObject {
                detached.setValue(detachable.detached(), forKey: property.name)
            } else {
                detached.setValue(value, forKey: property.name)
            }
        }
        return detached
    }

}

extension List: DetachableObject {

    func detached() -> List<Element> {
        let result = List<Element>()
        forEach {
            result.append($0.detached())
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking about an unmanaged version of a Realm object.

If so it's this process: create an object and persist it

```
class Person: Object {
   @Persisted var name = ""
}

let p = Person()
p.name = "Jay"

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(p)
}
```

later on, we want an unmanaged copy of Jay - it's not tied to realm, not live nor reflect any changes to jay and lives in memory only

```
let jay = realm.objects(Person.self).where { $0.name == "Jay" }.first!

let unmanagedJay = Person(value: p)

//unmanagedJay is not Persisted and is flexible for doing what's needed with that object
```

This should meet the requirements for 1) Abstracting the Persistence layer fully away, and then 2) Ability to pass around these objects

We use this process frequently in our macOS apps to place an unmanaged copy of an on object in for example, a sheet displayed to the user in the UI that can be freely manipulated without affecting or being affected by Realm

And you always have access to [frozen](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/threading/#frozen-objects) objects which are thread safe

> Freezing creates an immutable view of a specific object, collection,
> or realm. The frozen object, collection, or realm still exists on
> disk, and does not need to be deeply copied when passed around to
> other threads. You can freely share the frozen object across threads
> without concern for thread issues.

Likewise you can also use [@Threadsafe](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/threading/#sendable-conformance) property wrapper which conforms to sendable and allows passing thread-confined instances of objects.